# How to reuse code in an R function?

Tags: r, function, code-duplication

I have a block of code that I want to use several times inside a function (let's call it `myFunction`). I naturally want to avoid duplicating this block of code, but I can't find a way of reusing it short of putting it in an external file and sourcing that each time.

The first thing I tried was to put the duplicate code in an internal mini-function with no arguments (let's call it `internalFunction`. This meant that I could call `internalFunction` as needed; however, this masked the objects output by `internalFunction` from the main environment of `myFunction`.

I then tried using the `<<-` operator to assign output objects within `internalFunction`, so that they would be made available to the main environment of the `myFunction`. Unfortunately, this also makes those objects available to the global R environment outside `myFunction`, which I want to avoid.

Is there a way of writing a block of R code to an object and then calling that, or sourcing from an object instead of a file? I would really like to a) avoid duplicate code and b) include all code within a single file.

Comment: It is not clear to me why you can't just return the objects that internalFunction creates as return values that are returned to myFunction. Maybe if you posted the code you tried in a mini-example I could see what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you what you want would be some easy way to return multiple values to the calling function, this can be done with a list, as follows:

```
maxmin <- function(i1,i2){

  if (i1>i2){
    mx <- i1
    mn <- i2
  }  else
  {
    mn <- i1
    mx <- i2
  }
  rv <- list(min=mn,max=mx)
  return(rv)
}

r1 <- maxmin(3,4)
r2 <- maxmin(6,5)

print(sprintf("minimums %d %d",r1$min,r2$min))
print(sprintf("maximums %d %d",r1$max,r2$max))
```

Edit: I got rid of the quotes for the list element names, they are not necessary

Comment: That would work, but I would rather not return them as a list—multiple individual objects would be preferable.

Comment: AFAIK, R only can return one object, so you have to pack them up somehow.  I think this is fundamental to R. You could also pack them up as an S4 object if you prefer OO programming, but most people would just use a list.

Comment: So is this useful to you?

Comment: This is useful, but a bit disappointing. Would it be possible to assign the internalFunction objects in such a way that they're visible inside myFunction but not the global R environment?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way, but it feels tricky and is probably not be a good software engineering solution in most cases. Basically you can explictily access a variable in the parent's environment.

```
fun1 <- function(x)
{
    maxminenv <- function(i1,i2){
      if (i1>i2){
        mx <- i1
        mn <- i2
      }  else
      {
        mn <- i1
        mx <- i2
      }
      penv <- parent.frame()
      penv$min <- mn
      penv$max <- mx
    }
    maxminenv(3,4)
    print(sprintf("min:%d max:%d",min,max))
}
fun1()
```

For more information on environments see this excellent chapter in Hadley Wickam's new book. http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html